# Move-VMStorage failing with error 0x80070005

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2, live-migration

I'm issuing this command on the Hyper-V host SERVER2:

```
Clear; Get-VM | ForEach { 
  Write-Host "Migrating: "$_.Name;
  Move-VMStorage `
    -VM $_ `
    -DestinationStoragePath "\\SERVER1\D$";
}
```

Both servers are domain-joined, non-clustered.

This is the result I'm getting:

> Move-VMStorage : Storage migration for virtual machine 'ADMIN' (4F452569-7DB9-4606-9371-A905267A7B0F) failed with
>   error 'General access denied error' (0x80070005).
>   Migration did not succeed. Could not start mirror operation for the VHD file 'D:\Virtual Hard Disks\ADMIN.vhdx' to
>   '\SERVER1\D$\Virtual Hard Disks\ADMIN.vhdx': 'General access denied error'('0x80070005').
>   You do not have permission to perform the operation. Contact your administrator if you believe you should have
>   permission to perform this operation.

ACLs are correctly configured:

```
PS C:\Users\domain.admin> Get-Acl 'D:\Virtual Hard Disks' | FL


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\Virtual Hard Disks
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : DOMAIN\Domain Users
Access : CREATOR OWNER Allow  268435456
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Users Allow  CreateFiles, AppendData
         BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
         NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\Virtual Machines Allow  CreateFiles, AppendData, Read, Synchronize
         DOMAIN\SERVER2$ Allow  -2147483642
         DOMAIN\SERVER2$ Allow  CreateFiles, AppendData, Read, Synchronize
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:BAG:DUD:AI(A;OICIIO;GA;;;CO)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;CI;DCLC;;;BU)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;OICI;0x
         12008f;;;S-1-5-83-0)(A;CIIO;DCLCGR;;;S-1-5-21-369066176-630964511-2072824237-1119)(A;;0x12008f;;;S-1-5-21-3690
         66176-630964511-2072824237-1119)
```

and:

```
C:\Users\domain.admin>net localgroup Administrators
Alias name     Administrators
Comment        Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the compu
ter/domain

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator
DOMAIN\Domain Admins
The command completed successfully.

C:\Users\domain.admin>net group "Domain Admins"  <==(on the PDC)
Group name     Domain Admins
Comment        Designated administrators of the domain

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator            domain.admin
The command completed successfully.

C:\Users\domain.admin>whoami
DOMAIN\domain.admin
```

I've delegated Kerberos as discussed [here](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server-2012/windows-server-2012-storage-live-migration). Incoming and outgoing migrations are enabled on both machines, on Kerberos under any available network. Both firewalls are off.

I've contacted my administrator and I don't know what's wrong either.

Where to look next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I hadn't added the source and target machines to the target share's permissions:

```
# Create folder
MD X:\VMS

# Create file share
New-SmbShare -Name VMS1 -Path X:\VMS -FullAccess Domain\HVAdmin, Domain\HV1$, Domain\HV2$, Domain\HVC$

# Set NTFS permissions from the file share permissions
Set-SmbPathAcl VMS1
```

This is documented here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134187(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_Step3

Once I added them the migration sailed right through.